# Quadrature for logarithmic weight: $ \int_0^1 f(x) x \log x\, dx.$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, laguerre-polynomials

Is there a standard way to evaluate (numerically) the integral

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) x \log(x) dx .$$

I was trying the substitution $u = -2\log(x)$, and then use Gauss-Laguerre quadrature. But it accumulates way too many points in $x=0,$ so it converges too slowly.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try the Riemann Sum?

Comment: It converges as $1/n$ (number of samples). That's way too slow

Comment: Then have fun with [this list of quadratures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Numerical_integration_(quadrature)).

Comment: Since $\int_0^1 x^n \ln(x) dx = \dfrac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$, try expanding $f(x)$ in a power series and do standard linear least square fitting.

Comment: Have a look at [Table 3.5.14](https://dlmf.nist.gov/3.5#v).

Comment: Do you know how do they construct those tables? I saw that table and I don't have a clue

Comment: There’s a very good discussion in that DLMF chapter as well as in the monograph by Stroud and Secrest. But you might start simply with the description by [Golub and Welsch](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1969-23-106/S0025-5718-69-99647-1/S0025-5718-69-99647-1.pdf). Best of luck!

Comment: The combination $x \log(x)$ is well defined over the whole interval.  You don't want to split it apart and get the $\log$ term that goes to $- \infty$.  I would just feed your whole function to an integration routine.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting my comments into an answer, maybe helping future searches ...

As far as where to find a rule developed for working with a logarithmic singularity, a reference to a specific weighted Gaussian quadrature in DLMF:

- Have a look at [Table 3.5.14](https://dlmf.nist.gov/3.5#v).

In response to the OP's question on how these rules are calculated in practice:

- There’s a very good discussion in that DLMF chapter as well as in the monograph by Stroud and Secrest. But you might start simply with the description by [Golub and Welsch](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1969-23-106/S0025-5718-69-99647-1/S0025-5718-69-99647-1.pdf). Best of luck!